# Jquery how to select and use ajax loaded elements

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use ajax to load a page (example.html). I've got two buttons: one for ajax load function and another to act on loaded content. But it doesn't react. I tried to use:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#load")
        .click(function(){
        $("content").load("example.html");
    });
        $("#example_content").load(function(){
                  // some actions to loaded page 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the jQuery load function does not work like and event hook function, so the second .load call will expect to receive a url-like string to make a new request to the server to get more data (link http://api.jquery.com/load/).

If you want to do something with the content that was loaded into the div, I'd suggest you use the ajax method, which could be used like this:

```
$.ajax({

    //where is the data comming form? url
    url : "example.html",

    //what happens when the load was completed? the success function is called
    success : function(data){
         //add the content from the html to the div
         $("content").html(data.responseText);

         //do whatever else I want with the content that was just added to 'content'
        console.debug($('content')); // should show you all the html 
                                     // content written into that element 

        //my content specific funciton
        myFunction();
    }  
});
```

If you want to shorter way, using the $.get(url, success) function should help you, but this uses $.ajax inside, so you're better off using directly $.ajax.

Recap:

1) .load is a function that uses .get to fetch content. http://api.jquery.com/load/

2) .get has a success function, which writes the content received from the given url to the target element. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

3) .get is a function .ajax, which is the core of the jQuery ajax functionality.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/